# Show Entity List Builder in Block base?

Tags: 8, entities, blocks

I am making a custom block in Drupal 8 and I want to show my entity list builder in it.Is there any example or certain way by which I can show my entity list in the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

render() builds are renderable array for a table:

```
  public function build() {
    return \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getListBuilder('entity_type')->render();
  }
```

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityListBuilder.php/function/EntityListBuilder%3A%3Arender/8.5.x